# Canon 60D - exposure compensation with auto ISO in Manual mode

Tags: canon, exposure, canon-60d, wedding

I'm sure someone will be able to answer this conclusively fairly quickly, but as per the thread title, is there a way to set exposure compensation when using M mode but with the ISO set to automatic? In other words, lock the shutter and aperture but have the camera decide the ISO based on something other than a +/- 0 bias?

The reason I ask is that I'm shooting some friends' wedding soon, and during the low light sections in the church I would like to be able to keep my aperture and shutter constant (because the camera has a nasty tendency to lower these in preference to boosting the ISO resulting in soft shots), and spot meter off skin tones with a +1 exposure compensation affecting only the ISO.

Hopefully someone either tell me how to have the camera do this for me or else provide some tips for quickly and accurately doing this by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Set your desired shutter speed and aperture. Meter off the skin tones. Adjust ISO until the meter shows one stop of over exposure. Shoot.

Comment: Thanks - I will probably end up doing this or else using Av with auto ISO and keeping a close eye on the shutter speed. The problem with adjusting ISO based on skin tones on the 60D is that, unlike with the aperture and shutter, the exposure needle disappears from the viewfinder whilst selecting ISO.

Comment: And the list of reasons to use Nikon grows... ;)

Comment: True enough @ElendilTheTall, but with Canon I get to use Magic Lantern firmware, which is worth quite a lot of small niggles ;)